# Testing Vue Component with chai and vue-test-utils

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chai, vue-test-utils

I have component, in which I have a button. On click of a button, it calls Vuex action, which makes and API call to get some data and updates the store.

I want to test this feature. I am very new to testing in Vue.

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import store from '../../src/store'
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises'
import { assert } from 'chai';

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)

import SomeComponent from '../../src/templates/views/SomeComponent'

describe('test', () => {

    it('test', async () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(SomeComponent, { store, localVue })

        wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
        await flushPromises()
        console.log(store.state.users.length)
    })
})
```

it logs 0 as the API call is not completed. It would be helpful if anyone suggest some ideas to resolve this.